# Wordpress Multisite Https Forbidden Error

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress multisite on promise. The website are able to access from LAN with http, but not with https.

My goals right now is to publish the website to internet. I have reverse proxy and DNS server, but I am very sure that, the problem not from of them.

The following is the error:

```
Access forbidden!
        You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

        If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

        Error 403
        ddmc.co.id
        Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1b PHP/7.3.4
```

Here is the current configuration:

**WP_2_OPTION**

```
siteurl: http://ddmc.co.id/id
home: http://ddmc.co.id/id
```

**WP_SITE**

```
domain: ddmc.co.id
path: /
```

**WP_SITEMETA**

```
siteurl: http://ddmc.co.id
```

**WP_BLOGS**

```
domain: ddmc.co.id path:/
domain: ddmc.co.id path:/id/
```

**WP_OPTION**

```
domain: http://ddmc.co.id path:/
domain: http://ddmc.co.id path:/id/
```

**wp-config.php**

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'ddmc.co.id');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE','/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT', 1);
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M');
```

**htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

**htpd-vhosts**

```
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/ddmc">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have been troubleshoot this for a week without success, Please help.

Comment: Apache generally treats HTTPS as a separate virtual host on port 443. Have you set that up? And I'd try going to /index.php explicitly to check it's not a problem with the rewrite rule or CGI setup. You could also try running [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) in the background to check exactly which folder it's trying to read for the SSL case.

Comment: Not yet (I will try), Should I create csr and install the .cer to examp due I have installed certificate on Reverse Proxy.
Could you explain more about checking index.php rewrite rule?
I will trying install procmon.

Comment: I just realize that I have another xampp web server with port 80 configuration on virtualhost and running normal with reverse proxy.

Comment: I trying with another website (different IP, server) with same DNS and reverse proxy configuration. And it's works!. So I think the problem is because wordpress multisite. There is to many URL configuration in phpmyadmin and wp_config.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/hcml">
```

Is that `hcml` a typo? Basically somehow your route is wrong, or your file permissions to read the `WordPress` folder by the `Apache` user.

Comment: it's should be ddmc, just typo. 

I not sure about folder permission in windows, I just using default htaccess wordpress multisite.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem.

The problem is after I change Directory under httpd.conf from htdocs to my website folder.

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
```

change to:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/ddmc">
```

The problem now is, ya website redirect to dashboard. How I change document root without error forbidden access?